# Google Places API Access Denied (simple Access Key used)

Tags: google-places-api, text-search

Have checked everything, API console, generating new key, json/xml, yet to no avail.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=subway+station+in+Paris&sensor=false&key=myKey

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does the `status` property in the return JSON have the value: `REQUEST_DENIED`?

Answer (score 0):

have you forgotten to include `location`, and `radius` in your query? Some parameters are required. see [this](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search).